# Importing python classes in the Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am writing a GAE application and have run into an import problem.

My `app.yaml` has the following lines:

```
- url: /py/classes/  
  static_dir: py/classes

- url: /py/lib  
  static_dir: py/lib

- url: /py/bin/signin  
  script: py/bin/signin.py
```

I am keeping a python file, titled employee.py, containing the class employee, in the classes folder, and a signin.py script in the bin folder which tries - at the moment unsuccessfully - to import the employee class. I have tried, amongst others:

```
import employee  
import py.classes.employee
```

Neither option works. Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The `static_dir` configuration option can not be used to extend `PYTHONPATH`. Using it you can serve static files like images, stylesheet, or Javascript files.

If you want to use normal Python modules just put them next to your main Python files.

**Edit:**

Are your directories [Python packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages) that include the necessary `__init__.py` files?

Comment: I have empty \_\_init\_\_.py files in the /py and /py/classes paths. Trying import py.classes.employee or import classes.employee hasn't helped.

Comment: Correction: import py.classes.employee seems to work now. My bad. The \_\_init\_\_.py files seemed to be the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Any files specified as static files get uploaded separately from your code - they're not accessible by your Python code, so even with the PYTHONPATH set correctly, you won't be able to import them.